# C# - Load Mathematical Formula

Tags: c#

I have been given an Excel file. The Excel file has rows in it. The first column of each row has a formula that looks something like this:

```
'4.75+-3.12*log(x)+1.25*log(x)^2
```

I need to "load" this formula into C# so that I can do some calculations with it. My question is, if I had the text above, how do I convert it into a mathematical formula I can use in C#? I am successfully reading my Excel file. Yet, I'm not sure how to parse the formula into something I can actually use.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse each piece of the function into multiple parts and solve the equation?. I'm not aware of there being a quick and dirty way without some special rules parsing out the variables using orders of operations.

Comment: I'm trying to load the function so that I can pass different values in for X dynamically. Currently, when I use Mathos, I get an error that says `Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **infix** and **postfix** notations, as well as using the **Shunting Yard** algorithm will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Are you aware of a library that handles the infix and postfix notations for me?

Comment: If you Google "C# Shunting Yard", the first link looks promising and contains code.